# TradeDate import tinytext how to show Date Format 'yyyymmdd' of 20210111 or 2021-01-11

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Appears now to be RESOLVED
Added below

OS: openSUSE 15.2

Wish to use TradeDate in Date Format 'yyyymmdd' eg 20210111 or 2021-01-11
Column TradeDate imports ok as tinytext 
When select find TradeDate column not found how to sort into rising/falling dates. 
Column TradeDate not able to import in Date Format 'yyyymmdd' eg 20210111 or 2021-01-11 
How use SELECT to add extra column to show Date Format 'yyyymmdd' eg 20210111 or 2021-01-11

```
 Sample of the data
```

`MariaDB [(none)]> DESCRIBE  test.Equities1936 ;                                                                                                   +--------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field        | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| SecurityCode | char(20)      | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| TradeDate    | tinytext      | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| OpenPrice    | decimal(50,5) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| HighPrice    | decimal(50,5) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| LowPrice     | decimal(50,5) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| ClosePrice   | decimal(50,5) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| VolumeTraded | int(50)       | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+--------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
7 rows in set (0.001 sec)`

MariaDB [(none)]>

```
 Sample of the data as imported:
```

`MariaDB [(none)]> SELECT *  FROM test.Equities1936 WHERE SecurityCode LIKE 'AB%' HAVING  TradeDate LIKE '11 Jan 2021'  ;
+--------------+-------------+-----------+-----------+----------+------------+--------------+
| SecurityCode | TradeDate   | OpenPrice | HighPrice | LowPrice | ClosePrice | VolumeTraded |
+--------------+-------------+-----------+-----------+----------+------------+--------------+
| ABA          | 11 Jan 2021 |   6.12000 |   6.12000 |  6.04000 |    6.11000 |         6381 |
| ABB          | 11 Jan 2021 |   2.15000 |   2.17000 |  2.12000 |    2.15000 |       606112 |
| ABC          | 11 Jan 2021 |   3.28000 |   3.33000 |  3.25000 |    3.26000 |       372490 |
| ABP          | 11 Jan 2021 |   2.89000 |   2.91000 |  2.85000 |    2.86000 |      2365405 |
| ABR          | 11 Jan 2021 |   1.52500 |   1.59500 |  1.51000 |    1.57000 |       618566 |
| ABV          | 11 Jan 2021 |   0.03500 |   0.03500 |  0.03400 |    0.03400 |        60000 |
| ABY          | 11 Jan 2021 |   5.40000 |   5.46000 |  5.30000 |    5.35000 |        42417 |
+--------------+-------------+-----------+-----------+----------+------------+--------------+
7 rows in set (0.226 sec)`

MariaDB [(none)]>

## RESOLVED  :-)

## Source:

```
[stackoverflow.com/questions/46512102/date-between-in-mysql-not-correctly-working/46512206#46512206 ][1]
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46512102/date-between-in-mysql-not-correctly-working/46512206#46512206

Backup your data first and then I (think) the following will work

BEGIN;
ALTER TABLE `tablename`
ADD COLUMN `new_date` DATE;

UPDATE `tablename`
SET `new_date` = STR_TO_DATE(`date`, '%d/%m/%Y');

ALTER TABLE `tablename`
DROP COLUMN `date`;

ALTER TABLE `tablename`
CHANGE COLUMN `new_date` `date` DATE;
COMMIT;

Step By Step -

```
Add an extra column to store the data temporarily
Update the table and copy the current date column value (formatted DB friendly date) into the new temp column.
Remove the old column
Change the column name to the previous name so all existing queries work.
```

Then your query is as simple as

SELECT * FROM `tablename` where date between '2017-09-01' AND '2017-10-01'

MariaDB [db_test]> LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/mysqlfiles/MarketP.txt' INTO TABLE 5503_MarketP  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ;
Query OK, 4618 rows affected, 11852 warnings (0.230 sec)
Records: 4618  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 11852

MariaDB [db_test]> UPDATE `5503_MarketP` SET `new_date` = STR_TO_DATE(`Dated`, '%d %M %Y');
Query OK, 4618 rows affected (0.329 sec)
Rows matched: 39285  Changed: 4618  Warnings: 0

MariaDB [db_test]>
MariaDB [db_test]>
MariaDB [db_test]> SELECT Dated, new_date, Open, High, Low, Closes, Volume, (Volume*Closes)  FROM 5503_MarketP WHERE asxcode =
'AMP' ORDER BY new_date ;
+-------------+------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+----------+-----------------+
| Dated       | new_date   | Open    | High    | Low     | Closes  | Volume   | (Volume*Closes) |
+-------------+------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+----------+-----------------+
| 31 Oct 2022 | 2022-10-31 | 1.23000 | 1.26200 | 1.22500 | 1.26000 | 30164605 |  38007402.30000 |
| 01 Nov 2022 | 2022-11-01 | 1.26000 | 1.27500 | 1.24500 | 1.26000 | 11101042 |  13987312.92000 |
| 02 Nov 2022 | 2022-11-02 | 1.26500 | 1.28500 | 1.26000 | 1.28000 | 14409837 |  18444591.36000 |
| 03 Nov 2022 | 2022-11-03 | 1.27000 | 1.27000 | 1.25000 | 1.26000 |  8944926 |  11270606.76000 |
| 04 Nov 2022 | 2022-11-04 | 1.25500 | 1.26500 | 1.24500 | 1.25500 |  8121378 |  10192329.39000 |
| 07 Nov 2022 | 2022-11-07 | 1.27500 | 1.28500 | 1.25000 | 1.26000 |  6538624 |   8238666.24000 |
| 08 Nov 2022 | 2022-11-08 | 1.26500 | 1.27000 | 1.25500 | 1.26000 |  4368194 |   5503924.44000 |
| 09 Nov 2022 | 2022-11-09 | 1.26000 | 1.28000 | 1.25500 | 1.27500 |  8408256 |  10720526.40000 |
| 09 Nov 2022 | 2022-11-09 | 1.26000 | 1.28000 | 1.25500 | 1.27500 |  8408256 |  10720526.40000 |
+-------------+------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+----------+-----------------+
9 rows in set (0.046 sec)

MariaDB [db_test]>

MariaDB [db_test]>

Comment: [STR_TO_DATE() function](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/str_to_date/)

Comment: Better yet, cleanse the incoming data and put the date into a `DATE` column.

Comment: Am trying to import text data from the CSV received,  into my Table with YYYY-MM-DD format in 'TradeDate'.

Comment: Goal is to import the data from the CSV received,  into my Table with 'YYYY-MM-DD format' in 'TradeDate'. 

Or how to have the TradeDate data convert the TinyText into another FIELD where it shows as DATE FORMAT  'YYYY-MM-DD'.

What do I need change to get the DATE FORMAT  ? .